# JIRA Xray connection with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jira-xray

Hello everyone I'm newbie there,

I seeking some solution how to connect Jenkins with Xray test management plugin, because I need change condition of test result after Jenkins finished execution of current test. Is there any person who have experience with that?

Answer (score 2):

I know of 2 ways to do that:

1. use the XRay Jenkins plugin : https://confluence.xpand-addons.com/display/XRAY/Integration+with+Jenkins
2. use curl to call XRay REST APIs : https://confluence.xpand-addons.com/display/XRAY/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST

Comment: If you are going to link to external sources, you need to provide an explanation in your answer as well.